# How to translate POST parameter into Action parameter

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-mvc-4

I can't get POST parameter sort. What is it the type? How to place correct "sort" parameter? I tried object, array, specific object with sender property but nothing helped.

**Post Body:**

```
current=1&rowCount=10&sort[sender]=asc&searchPhrase=&id=b0df282a-0d67-40e5-8558-c9e93b7befed
```

**Code:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OrganizationPosts( int current, int rowCount, string sort = null, string searchPhrase = null )
{           
    return Json( 
        new { 
            current = 1,
            rowCount= 10,
            rows = new[]{ 
                new { id= 16, post = "post 16" },
                new { id= 117, post = "post 17"}, 
                new { id= 19, post = "post 19"} 
            },
            total = 1123 
        });
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't help. Request["sort[post]"] returns right value but i can'r predict what column will be sorted

Comment: what is sort[sender] ? what does [sender] indicate here ?

Comment: [sender] is column name for sorting

Comment: As you have done right now, that wont work since it maps the exact name of the parameter and will get value following that. So you need to write `sort` in your string or change it to `sort[sender]` in code-behind or write them both separately.

Answer (score 2):

The model binder won't bind sort[sender] to sort, if you change your request to just be sort=asc it will work.

If you need the sender as well, just add the sender, add it as a separate parameter, i.e.:

```
current=1&rowCount=10&sort=asc&sender=someSender&searchPhrase=&id=b0df282a-0d67-40e5-8558-c9e93b7befed
```

and change the method signature to:

```
public ActionResult OrganizationPosts( int current, int rowCount, string sort = null, string sender = null, string searchPhrase = null)
```

If you can't change the request, you'll have to create a custom model binder:
Here's a link that can help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder

Comment: I can't change request parameters but have to parse an existing one signature. There is parameter sort[SortedColumnName] = "asc/desc"

Comment: Basicly I want to implement  jQuery Bootgrid on my MVC page and cant parse sorting parameter

Comment: @Andriy I've updated my answer, the best option for you is to create a custom model binder. You can loop over all the parameters, and get the "sender" value this way. I imagine you will be getting requests with sender[columnName]=asc, where column name is a value you must be able to read. The doc page for the Form collection has an example for iterating over all the properties that might help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank's. It seems to be the best way to solve this solution. I will try

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue

```
public class SortDirection
{
    public string prop { get; set; }
    public string direction { get; set; }
}

public class CampaignModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string post { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class SortModelBinder
    :System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder
{
    Type currType = typeof( CampaignModel );

    public object BindModel( ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingContext bindingContext )
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var retVal = new SortDirection();
        foreach( var prop in currType.GetProperties() )
        {
            string dir = request.Form.Get( string.Format( "sort[{0}]", prop.Name ) );
            if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( dir ) )
            {
                retVal.prop = prop.Name;
                retVal.direction = dir;
            }
        }

        return retVal;
    }
}

public ActionResult OrganizationPosts( int current, int rowCount, [ModelBinder( typeof( SortModelBinder ) )] SortDirection sort, string sender = null, string searchPhrase = null )
    {           
...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Andriy, I like your solution, but for my needs I made it a bit more generic, so we don't need to make separate ModelBinder for each grid in the system.

```
public class BootgridSortModelBinder<T> : System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;

        Type typeParameterType = typeof(T);

        foreach (var prop in typeParameterType.GetProperties())
        {
            string dir = request.Form.Get(string.Format("sort[{0}]", prop.Name));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dir))
            {
                return new BootgridSortDirection() { prop = prop.Name, direction = dir };
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

and then in the Controller:

```
public string GetJsonGridData(int current, int rowCount, [ModelBinder(typeof(BootgridSortModelBinder<SomeModel>))] BootgridSortDirection sort, string searchPhrase = null)
```